# ubuntu server version different with desktop version

Tags: ubuntu, diff

I was surprising during check my ubuntu system. Since mid 2011 until now i'm use this different version of ubuntu. I found that my server is `ubuntu 10.04` and my desktop is `ubuntu 10.10`.

But until now i found no problem. It caused by for desktop I have installed by own self but for server is by another person.
Is that something bad will be happen if I still in this way? how do you think?

Comment: So exactly what problem are you having? If none, why are you worrying about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it makes sense for the server to be Ubuntu 10.04 as this is LTS (Long-Term Support) version. Generally, it is not a good idea to have servers on non-LTS versions, as those have shorter lifecycle and tend to be more ... unstable, if you will. However, there is nothing wrong for a desktop to be any version or OS. As long as it talks to the server when and if needed, all should be good. It is generally not a good idea to **just** upgrade the server to 12.04. As this is new LTS, you still may run into troubles and need to take the necessary precautions - check your system, make a test run, etc. After you are sure your services are up and running on the newer version, then you could proceed with the upgrade.

Comment: +1 and if you are using LDAP+kerb5 authentication, pay special attention to that point as until now I have my workstations still on 11.04 as I couldn't make it work on 11.10 test workstations. I am waiting a little more to test and upgrade server+workstations to 12.04... I had some problems in the past too in hardy(?) with difference in ssh methods for LDAP when one version was using openssh and the other gnutls.

Comment: Upgrade from 10.04 LTS to 12.04 is not recommended in 12.04 release notes. I've tried to upgrade a test machine and ran into weird bugs.

Answer (score 3):

> Is that something bad will be happen if I still in this way?

Unless there are special circumstances that we don't or can't know about, there is no issue with running two different versions of the same distro, two different distros, or two different operating systems on two different machines.

Comment: maybe the best way I will upgrade both using liveCD to 12.04.